# How to change table's cells alignment except the first row

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, alignment

I have the following table. I want to make all cells alignment to the right except the first row where the table's headers, I need the alignment centre. I used `\multicol{1}{c}{col.}` for the header cells, but I am wondering, is there a better way without adding too much text to the table header's code? I want the code to be clean.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array, makecell} 

\begin{document}

\title{Title}

\begin{abstract}
Abstract  
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\begin{table}
    \caption{Table's caption.}
    \label{tab:table1}
    \begin{tabular}{llll}
        \toprule
        Col 1   & Col 2  & Col 3    & Col 4    \\
        \midrule
        item1   & item2  & item3    & item4 \\
        \hline
        item11  & item22 & item33   & item44     \\
        \hline
        item111 & item222 & item333 & item444     \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}   
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you use `makecell` in your document, let exploit its macro `\thead`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\maketitle

\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
    \caption{Table's caption.}
    \label{tab:table1}
    \begin{tabular}{llll}
        \toprule
    \thead{Col 1}   & \thead{Col 2}  & \thead{Col 3}    & \thead{Col 4}    \\
        \midrule
        item1   & item2  & item3    & item4 \\
        \hline
        item11  & item22 & item33   & item44     \\
        \hline
        item111 & item222 & item333 & item444     \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]

edit: of-topic, i would not use `\hline in your table. without them table will looks nicer (to my opinion, of course):

[image]